# Install python package with python

Tags: package-management, python

I will maybe repeat the same question but, when I read "How to intall python packages on Ubuntu" everybody say to "Enter python install file.py" or "Enter sudo" but when I follow these instructions, my python say ">>> python install setup.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" so, I ask at the community, if she can help me. Thanks

Informations : Python version : 2.7.6
Ubuntu version : 14.04 LTS
Package I want to install : distribute-O.7.3 ; win32 ; pip-develop

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The package `distribute 0.7.3` is a **deprecated** fork of `Setuptools`, install it only if you can't install `Setuptools` and need a compatibility layer.
**Before** anything, execute in a terminal (xterm or Terminal are both fine) `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` to install the distribution version of setuptools.
If you really need to proceed, follow this mini-guide to one of the possible installation procedures for that specific version of distribute:

1. download the sources from [PyPI (official Python repository)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute/0.7.3).
2. extract the sources in a directory with an archive management utility.
3. from a terminal use the `cd` command to set the directory with the extracted sources as your working directory.
4. in the directory execute `python setup.py install` (or `sudo python setup.py install` if you need the administrative rights) to install the package with the included installer.

If current python version is correct and the sources are functional, the package will be installed in your system.
The same procedure is valid for the other packages and the choice of installing them from the Ubuntu repository or from source is only yours, i *suggest* the Ubuntu repo packages if possibile.
For example, you could use `sudo apt-get install python-pip` to install PIP from the Ubuntu repo.
Some packages may support the direct installation with PIP (`pip install PACKAGE_NAME` will fetch, download and install those pakages).

Please, feel free to comment under here if you have more questions or if I misunderstood your request and don't forget to press the left UP arrow if I'm of any help.